# Quickblox: how can I show the last 25 messages? Android

Tags: android, quickblox

I was wondering how I can show the recent 25 messages in the chat. On the chat at the top there will be a button to show the older 25 and so on...

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems have you encountered? Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to order the retrieved data according the date in descending order, then create a`Paging` to manage the display of your messages. Regardless you are loading messages data from a local database of from online web services, you need to arrange the retrieval of the data by segmenting the data into `Pages`.

> You define the the page size (equal to 25 in your case), and define
>   the page number. For example, the rows for Page 1, first row:
>   (page-1)*size = (1-1)*25 = 0, last row: (first row + size - 1).

If you have  a button to load the next 25 rows, you need to increment the pages by 1, `so when you have page = 2 , index of row 1 = (2-1)*25=25, last row index = 25+25-1=49.`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these messages are saved in a database, so you could get all messages and show just the first 25 iterating through them.